# put a lot of data automatically into HTML with css

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of data and want to put it into the website, 
but I don't know how to put a lot of data automatically into HTML with css?

the type of data includes product title, country and a reference link.

Thanks!!

Comment: what you need is [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide more context to your problem. There are hundreds of ways to put out data into a webpage.

- What technology does the website use? -> [Which technology is right for my website](https://www.intechnic.com/blog/which-technology-is-right-for-my-website/)
- Is it a static webpage with static data? -> [Basics of a Static Website](https://www.webnots.com/basics-of-a-static-website/)
- Is this website connected to a database or API? -> [How to use an API](https://technologyadvice.com/blog/information-technology/how-to-use-an-api/)
- What format do you need to display this data in? -> [HTML Formatting](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp)

These are just a few questions you need to address to get a specific answer. If the website uses something like PHP framework, then you should look into templating languages, like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) or [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade)